# i want to count table rows from sql database with between two times

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `time_from` >= '".$time_from."'
AND `time_to` <= '".$time_to."' AND `member_id` = '".$member_id."'
AND status ='Active'
```

After getting values query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE time_from >= '2pm'
AND time_to <= '5pm'
AND `member_id` = '5'
AND date = '2017-07-08'
AND status ='Active'
```

Gtting answer correct if `time_from = 2pm` and `time_to = 5pm` but if provide value like `time_from 3pm` to `time_to 4pm` it display`num_rows '0'` because in database table there is `time_from` value `2pm` and `time_to` value `5pm`

I want the `sql` query if user entered `time_from` `3pm` and `time_to` `4pm` or `2pm` and `4pm` or any value in between `2pm` and `5pm`, the result should be `num_rows 1` or more if more than one entry is matched with provided values

Comment: can you show me the table structure...

Comment: If you want to count rows what for you select `*` instead of `count() `?

Comment: active_samaj_seva_id |member_id | name |km | date | time_from| time_to |status
1 |  5  | arun  | 50 | 2017-07-06 | 2pm | 5pm |  Active

Comment: $search_data = mysqli_query($con,$search_query);
 $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_data);
 if($num_rows >0)
 {
  $response['message'] = "Fail";
  $response['data'] = "";
  $response['error_msg'] = "This information already exist";
 }
 else
 {
  $query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`member_id`,`name`,`km`,`time_from`,`time_to`,`status`,`added_date`) VALUES ('".$member_id."','".$name."','".$km."','".$time_from."','".$time_to."','".$status."','".$added_date."')";

Answer (score 0):

This will not as give count as query is treating 2pm as string not as timestamp.
you need to alter your column from varchar/text to date time and save time in required format.